# Flurry Usage Data when No Internet Connection

Tags: iphone, flurry

I have just implemented Flurry into my iPhone app. My app is targeting a market in which internet connection is spotty at best so there will usually be no active connection. I am wondering, does Flurry do anything to handle the situation when there is no internet? Should I take extra measures to handle this issue myself? I've emailed the support team at Flurry but have not received a response.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flurry caches the data in the device until it can get an Internet connection to transmit all the data. This all happens transparently in the background so the user doesn't see any warnings or errors.

Source: [Product Guy at Flurry](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/business-legal-app-store/65014-flurry-analytics-what-does-happen-if-there-no-connection.html#post268212)

Comment: Cool. Does the app have to be opened to transmit the data, or will this just happen once the device connects to a network regardless of it the app is open or not?

Comment: The app needs to be open because an app can't run arbitrary code (there are some exceptions such as geolocation) while it's closed/in background mode. I've been using Flurry for some time and it does eventually transmit the data when it can and works well.

Comment: Is there any way around that, possibly using some sort of notification process to push the cached data without the app having to be open?

Comment: @Kevin_TA I'd really caution against 'baiting' your users to open your app, just so you can get analytics data.

Comment: That's not what I meant. I meant like say, the mail app doesn't have to be open in order to alert you when you have a new message. So that is receiving data without being open. You know?

Comment: @Kevin_TA - Apple gets to do things that you don't get to do.

Comment: Haha. Fair enough... but how about Words with Friends letting you know when someone played a word. Or a sports app that tells you when a goal was scored. How is that done?

Comment: Those are with push notifications and thats fair game because the app is letting you know something useful so you don't have to have the app glued open to know when a friend played a word or a goal was scored. I think what Wayne is getting at is you can't have your app receive push notifications saying just open me or use me because that is borderline spam.